# HKStatistics Collection Query Only returning partial Data

Tags: swift, swiftui, healthkit

Below is my query. When I print out the data in my ContentView section (below), accurate data from only the past week is shown and every other day is "nil" when I know for sure there is data for those days even when the predicate should go back 30 days.

```
func makeElevationQuery(completion: @escaping (HKStatisticsCollection?) -> ()) {
            
            let elevationType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.flightsClimbed)!
            
            let calendar = NSCalendar.current
        
        let endDate = Date()
        
        let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -30, to: endDate)
        
        let anchorDate = Date.mondayAt12AM()
        
        let daily = DateComponents(day : 1)
        
        let summariesWithinRange = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: .strictStartDate)
        
        elevationQuery = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: elevationType, quantitySamplePredicate: summariesWithinRange, options: .cumulativeSum, anchorDate: anchorDate, intervalComponents: daily)
        
        elevationQuery!.initialResultsHandler = {elevationQuery, statisticsCollection, error in
            completion(statisticsCollection)
        }
        
        healthstore.execute(elevationQuery!)
        
    }
}


extension Date {
    static func mondayAt12AM() -> Date {
        return Calendar(identifier: .iso8601).date(from: Calendar(identifier: .iso8601).dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: Date()))!
    }
}
```

Content View Part:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var fitness = main()
    @State var final = HKActivitySummary()
    @State var MonthElevation = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.flightsClimbed)
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("refresh"){
                    fitness.authorizeHealthkit()
                    fitness.makeQuery() { (summary) in
                    final = summary
                    fitness.makeElevationQuery { statisticsCollection in
                        if let statisticsCollection = statisticsCollection {
                            let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -30, to: Date())
                            let endDate = Date()
                            statisticsCollection.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate!, to: endDate) {
                                (statistics, stop) in
                                
                                let count = statistics.sumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: .count())
                                print(count) //prints out flights climbed on that day correctly for first week only but just "nil" another 23 times (because I had it go back a month)
                            }
                        }
                            
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on watchOS or iOS? Sounds like you might be on watchOS since watch only has around a weeks worth of data. See [earliestPermittedSampleDate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614166-earliestpermittedsampledate).

Comment: Ah yes. watchOS. That would explain it